# Do 跟我读 (gēn wǒ dú) and 跟我念 (gēn wǒ niàn) have the same meaning ("read with me")?

Tags: difference, synonyms

These two sentences are similar, both meaning "read with me":

> 跟我读
> <sub>(gēn wǒ dú)</sub>
>
> 跟我念
> <sub>(gēn wǒ niàn)</sub>

I've said the first one when I teach English to kids.  (They don't usually 跟我读, but you know...）

**Question**: Do 跟我读 and 跟我念 have the same meaning?

The translations on jukuu.com for [请跟我读](http://jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E8%AF%B7%E8%B7%9F%E6%88%91%E8%AF%BB) is "please read after me" and for [请跟我念](http://jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E8%AF%B7%E8%B7%9F%E6%88%91%E5%BF%B5) "repeat after me, please", which suggests they're the same.

Comment: Yes, they have the same meaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:**

> In the context of '跟我念', the standard version should be 唸 (recite). However, 念 is also an acceptable variant

The difference between 跟我读 and 跟我念

> 读出 = **read out**
>
> 念出 = **recite** / **read out**

In 跟我读 (follow me and read) ,  there have to be some written text for you to read it out.

In 跟我念 (follow me and read/ follow me and recite), you can either read from some written text or recite words from memory

> 念 literally means "recite ".  For example 念經, 念诗, 念咒

*We can use 念 interchangeably with 读 (read out)  because "recite" can mean "recite what you are reading"*

Answer (score 1):

跟我读 and 跟我念 mean the same in the setting you are applying at.

In order to make it more clear to kids, you could put more words like "大家一起跟我读，我读一句，你们读一句, 好吧？". If you could get an acknowledge of that "好吧"， there you go!

Answer (score 0):

跟我读:(gēn wǒ dú）Passive acceptance.
跟我念：（gēn wǒ niàn）Active pursuit of knowledge.

“念”的义项有：“读、学习、回忆、思想、考虑”的含义，如：“大声念出来、去学校念书、念他的好、念头、念及他当年的功劳”等。观察汉字的偏旁部首，从“心”，应为“用心读”之义。"Read" the meanings are: "reading, learning, memory, thinking, thinking of" meaning, such as: "loudly read aloud, to go to school, his good, idea, concept and his credit", etc. Observe the side of Chinese characters, from "heart", should be "heart read".

“读”的义项有：“学习、阅读”的含义。如：“读书破万卷、默读、朗读”等，观察偏旁部首从“言”，应为强调“发音行为”。 The meaning of "reading" is the meaning of "learning and reading". For example, "reading books, reading books, reading aloud, reading aloud" etc., observing the side of the side of the side from "speech", should emphasize "pronunciation behavior".